# Laravel 5 Repository inside service provider

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following problem in my laravel 5 project. I have a service provider for form macros named MacroServiceProvider.php. Some macros should receive data from the database, I'm currently using the model and getting the results with eloquent but I want to use repositories instead, so I created my repository but I can't inject this directly to my service provider.

I want something like this:

```
...
public function register(MyRepoInterface $repo)
    {
        $registers = $repo->findAll();
        Form::macro...
    }
...
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't think you can do what are you asking, and I think you are misunderstanding the way providers work and what they are intended for.

In providers, you usually say what are the bindings among interfaces and implementations, so that when you do dependency injection in your application code, it works. I'm pretty sure they are not intended for doing real stuff.

For what you say about your code, I imagine something like this:

- a repository interface (`MyRepoInterface`) with a real implementation using `Eloquent` (say `EloquentMyRepo`)
- a facade, say `Macro`, so that you can do `Macro::myMacro1()`, `Macro::myMacro2()`, etc.
- the methods `myMacro1()`, `myMacro2()`, etc, use the repository to get some data from the db and then call some methods from the `Form` facade

If I'm right, then I suggest something like this.

## Repository

Define the interface in the file `MyRepoInterface.php` with

```
interface MyRepoInterface 
{
    public function findAll();

    // ... your other repo methods
}
```

and an implementation `EloquentMyRepo.php` with

```
class EloquentMyRepo implements MyRepoInterface
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        // ... do what you need
    }
}
```

## Facade

Define a facade file `MacroFacade.php` with this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class MacroFacade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'macro';
    }
}
```

## Service class

Define your macro service class in a file `MacroService.php`, where you can use dependency injection and access your repository. In this class you define your `myMacro1()`... methods.

```
class MacroService
{
    protected $myRepo;

    public function __construct(MyRepoInterface $myRepo)
    {
        $this->myRepo = $myRepo;
    }

    public function myMacro1()
    {
        // access the repo
        $items = $this->myRepo->findAll();
        // ... do something with $items and finally return a string
        return Form::macro(...);
    }

    public function myMacro2($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        // ... use the parameters to do something else
    }
}
```

## Bindings

In your `Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file, go to the `register()` method and add

```
public function register()
{
    // ...
    $this->app->bind('App\MyRepoInterface', 'App\EloquentMyRepo');
    // ...
}
```

so that when you use `MyRepoInterface` in dependency injection, Laravel knows it has to use an instance of `EloquentMyRepo`.

Now, let's create a service provider for your macro service. Create a file `Providers/MacroServiceProvider.php` and put in it

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('macro', 'App\MacroService');
    }
}
```

Now, when we need the facade that is registered as `macro`, an instance of `MacroService` is used.

## Configuration

We finally need some changes to the configuration. Open the `config/app.php` file, add the new provider

```
...
'providers' => [
    ...
    'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
    ...
    'App\Providers\MacroServiceProvider',
],
```

(note that the `MacroServiceProvider` is declared *after* the `AppServiceProvider`.)

Add the alias for the facade:

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Macro' => 'App\MacroFacade',
],
```

Done!

## What happens

Let's suppose you call

```
...
Macro::myMacro1();
...
```

in your code. How the right method is called?

1. `Macro` is an alias handled by the `MacroFacade` class
2. The facade is registered in the IoC with the `macro` name by the `getFacadeAccessor()` method of `MacroFacade`
3. The `MacroServiceProvider` registered the `MacroService` class as an implementation for `macro`
4. An instance of `MacroService` must be created, but it has `MyRepoInterface` as dependency
5. The `AppServiceProvider` said Laravel to use `EloquentMyRepo` when `MyRepoInterfice` is required
6. So an instance of `EloquentMyRepo` is created and it is used to create an instance of `MacroService`
7. `Macro` has been resolved to an instance of `MacroService`
8. Laravel calls the `myMacro1()` method of that instance

I hope this can clarify a bit what happens.

Comment: I'll try doing what you mentioned. I'm not defining the macros in the service provider, i have a file that extends Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder, so i can call my macros as Form::macro instead of using a Facade. In my service provider i call: $this->app->bindShared('form',... $form = new Macros(...).

Comment: I'm not sure I understood: you want to use `Form::macro()` and access your `macro()` method that extends the `FormBuilder` class?

Comment: It worked! I followed what you told and now it's working. The only thing that i'm doing differently is that i'm using a HtmlServiceProvider instead the default service provider and also using a Macro class that extends the FormBuilder class to build my macros, but i do all my queries in the facade. Thanks.